# Compare the difference between two list<string>

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list, compare

I'am trying to check the difference between two `List<string>` in `c#`.

Example:

```
List<string> FirstList = new List<string>();
List<string> SecondList = new List<string>();
```

The `FirstList` is filled with the following values:

```
FirstList.Add("COM1");
FirstList.Add("COM2");
```

The `SecondList` is filled with the following values:

```
SecondList.Add("COM1");
SecondList.Add("COM2");
SecondList.Add("COM3");
```

Now I want to check if some values in the `SecondList` are equal to values in the `FirstList`.

If there are equal values like: COM1 and COM2, that are in both lists, then filter them from the list, and add the remaining values to another list.

So if I would create a new `ThirdList`, it will be filled with "COM3" only, because the other values are duplicates.

How can I create such a check?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try to use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) LINQ extension method, which takes items only from the first list, that are not present in the second. Example is given below:

```
List<string> ThirdList =  SecondList.Except(FirstList).ToList();
```

You can print the result using the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ThirdList));
```

Or

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ThirdList));
```

Note: Don't forget to include: `using System.Diagnostics;`

**prints:**

```
COM3
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of this simple, but clever solution. It works perfectly and I will accept this as my answer, when stackoverflow allows me to do so:)

Comment: Note that this is the Set difference between the lists. This will not tell you if you if list1 has two copies of "COM1" and list2 has three copies of "COM1"

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx):

```
var inBoth = FirstList.Intersect(SecondList);
```

or to detect strings which are only in one of both lists, [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
var inFirstOnly = FirstList.Except(SecondList);
var inSecondOnly = SecondList.Except(FirstList);
```

To get your `ThirdList`:

```
List<string> ThirdList = inSecondOnly.ToList();
```

Comment: +1 for bringing `Intersect`. I always love to remember basic set operations.

Answer (score 5):

Than for this king of reuqirement you can can make use of `Except` function.

```
List<string> newlist =  List1.Except(List2).ToList();
```

---

or you can do this , so the below one create new list three which contains items that are not common in list1 and list2

```
var common = List1.Intersect(List2);

var list3 = List1.Except(common ).ToList();
list3.AddRange(List2.Except(common ).ToList());
```

the above one is help full when list1 and list2 has differenct item like

```
List<string> list1= new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
```

The FirstList is filled with the following values:

```
list1.Add("COM1");
list1.Add("COM2");
list1.Add("COM4");
```

The SecondList is filled with the following values:

```
list2 .Add("COM1");
list2 .Add("COM2");
list2 .Add("COM3");
```

by using above code `list3 contains COM4 and COM3.`