# comparing two List<string>() in c#

Tags: c#, list

Why in the below code **s==p** returns false ?

```
List<string> s=new List<string>();
s.Add("one");
List<string> p=new List<string>();
p.Add("one");

string result = "";

if (s == p)
{
    result = "unequal";
}
else
{
    result = "equal";

}
     what does this indicates?
```

Comment: Because they're different lists, even if they contain the same information.

Comment: You are comparing objects -- this is not the type of comparison you think you are getting.  The comparison you are doing only tells you if the two references are the same object.  Look at the following post for some examples of how you might accomplish the comparison you intended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612162/compare-the-difference-between-two-liststring

Comment: Yes, what Rob and David said. It looks like you want to compare the actual **values** in the lists instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-list

Comment: Actually s == p returns true in your case (was valid with the line p = s;) - it is your resulting string is wrong (should be if (s == p) { result = "equal"; })

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? I know it's relatively basic but it seems like a pretty valid logical question. Is there a rule I should know about?

Comment: SO should introduce a rule that no downvotes has to be allowed  without proper explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The `==` in this case is comparing if the two instances of lists are the same. It's not comparing the contents at all. And since they are not the same instance then they are unequal.

Try using `SequenceEqual` instead:

```
List<string> s=new List<string>();
s.Add("one");
List<string> p=new List<string>();
p.Add("one");

string result = "";

if (s.SequenceEqual(p))
{
    result = "equal";
}
else
{
    result = "unequal";
}
```

Comment: If im assigning s=p how the result returns equal. I declared it as two list points to two different memory location.

Comment: @Ammu - sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I assigned the value of s to p  , p=s;  which returns true. Even both list are two different object, how in that case, it returns true.

Comment: @Ammu - sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. You're not assigning anything. You're comparing.